# High resolution flat view box cover images

Tags: set-database

Where can I find high-resolution, manufacturer quality LEGO box cover image files with flat view, i.e. without perspective view?

[image]

Is there a set database somewhere that collects them? I have tried searching but so far without success.

Comment: this is only a guess but Lego would probably do what it can to make them not appear on the Internet. Making them available would make it easier to manufacturers of fakes... and Google is american company, so DMCA applies.

Comment: No, according to their fair use policy here: https://www.lego.com/en-us/legal/legal-notice/fair-play they currently don't mind scans of box-art under certain conditions... Unfortunately, no-one has currently done the effort to start a large repository of high-quality box-art scans...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lego does not release them for most sets so you might have to do what we at Brickset do when we want them and use software to correct the 'distortion'.

Comment: I've been using Paint.NET and the [quadrilateral reshape plugin](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/111095-help-with-image-skew-quadrilateral-reshape/) to achieve this, but it takes a lot of time and the result is not optimal. (Amusingly, using the result in a Google image search can sometimes locate manufacturer quality flat-view images!) What tool do you recommend?