# Alternate builds for classic space sets

Tags: space

I'm looking for a full list of the alternate builds on the boxes of Classic Space.  Any ideas?

Comment: Since the alternate builds have only been printed on the boxes, [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/high-resolution-flat-view-box-cover-images) seems to go in the same direction. There was no success, so far, with scans of LEGO boxes, but maybe some collector did this for Classic Space sets. It is a pity, that there are no alternate builds any more on the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone has 'reverse engineered' them from the box images in this eurobricks [thread](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/107606-classic-space-alternate-builds/).

Hope that helped.

Comment: those are not official alternates but rather people using their imagination to think up their own alternates. Which was how it was intended at the time, and how I spent many evenings after school work building contraptions.

Comment: @jwenting oh ok.